# Button move in design Android Studio SDK

Tags: android, android-studio, sdk

Android Design Button, Buttons got three in a row but when I click on any of them so I moved others or MOVE away. I need your advice to all Buttons were fixed in one place. Thank you very much for your help

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/activity_main_page"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:background="#151515"
tools:context="com.merrychristmas.MainPage">

<Button
    android:layout_width="64dp"
    android:layout_height="64dp"
    android:id="@+id/ch_txt_cze"
    android:elevation="0dp"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/ch_txt_eng"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:background="@drawable/cze" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="64dp"
    android:layout_height="64dp"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/ch_txt_cze"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:id="@+id/ch_txt_ger"
    android:background="@drawable/ger" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="64dp"
    android:layout_height="64dp"
    android:id="@+id/ch_txt_eng"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/textView1"
    android:background="@drawable/eng" />
```

Thanks guys for help

Comment: Where is text View 1 in xml ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to toggle visibility by clicking. Make button `View.INVISIBLE` instead of `View.GONE`